# Windows Python Virtualenv Install PIL and MySQL

Tags: python, django, pip

In windows I'm having trouble installing things such as **PIL** and **MySQL** inside my **virtualenv** for **Python 2.7 64-bit**.
I've downloaded extensions from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and installed them globally.

But how can I get them to apply to my **virtualenv** installation? 
If I do a re-installation of virtualenv for my project, will it inherit the currently installed **PIL** and **MySQL**?

My main error is when I do a pip installed: **error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat**
Now what I've read is I need Visual Studio to compile such things, and I'm hoping this isn't the only way to get things working.

Comment: What are you `pip installing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your environment with the `--system-site-packages` option. Once you are in the virtual environment, if you try to import a package that isn't installed, it will try to find it in the global site packages and only if it can't find it there will it raise an `ImportError`.

This is by far the simplest way to do what you are trying on Windows - short of creating your own build environment - which I can tell you from my experience isn't always guaranteed to work.

If you do go with this approach, make sure you still add the package (and ideally [pin it](http://nvie.com/posts/pin-your-packages/)) in  your `requirements.txt` file. This way if you were to deploy it on another environment, you will not miss any dependencies.